# Как версионировать динамические библиотеки под linux?

Tags: linux, библиотеки, g++, ld, версионность

Под windows в dll можно добавить версию, наименование продукта и так далее. Примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать нечто подобное под linux? Можно конечно сделать пакет на библиотеку и там все указать, но проблема в том что пользователь может поменять библиотеку вручную без переустановки соответствующего пакета, и пакетный менеджер это никак не отследит.

Поэтому хотелось бы в самом файле четко указать его версию.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может, я не понял вопроса, но вам нужно сгенерировать поле DT_SONAME для вашей библиотеки, где и будет храниться версия. Используйте ключи -hname или -soname=name для компоновщика.
Есть неплохая "библия" для создателей библиотек от Ульриха Дреппера. Не знаю, есть ли она на русском, но на английском она доступна: [How to write shared libraries](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/dsohowto.pdf). Если не хотите читать всю, переходите сразу к главе 3.3